# fabric.textbox is not working for google chrome?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, canvas, fabricjs

I am deleting all the text in text box or i am removing each letter by using backspace.After removing all letters again am  doing typing but its blocked.Its not allowed to move.

Comment: Make a fiddle or use snippet here , to produce your problem.

Comment: I have the same issue on one of my mac laptops... The same code works perfectly on one machine, but not working on second...
Chrome version is Version 66.0.3359.181 (Official Build) (64-bit) on both macs

Answer (score 0):

A [data URI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs) (or data URL) is a string, which contains the data of a small file, prefixed by a `data:` scheme and the MIME type of the file.
For binary data, the file is often converted to base64 in order to be able to represent all the bytes in a format which is compatible with URI rules.

The [Blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/Blob) constructor expects as first argument a list of data that will be appended in the resulting Blob.

Here you are trying to create a Blob from a dataURI directly, this means that your file will hold `data:image/png;base64,iVB0Rw0...` as text/plain, literally.

You can check this by opening the resulting file in a TextEditor, since yes, this is just a text file that you did create.

```js
var blob = new Blob([c.toDataURL()], {type: 'image/png'});
var f = new FileReader();
f.onload = function(){console.log(f.result)};
f.readAsText(blob);
```

```html
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
```

What you want is to extract the data contained in this dataURI, before appending it to your Blob.

The easy solution when available, is to use the Fetch API:

```js
var dataURI = c.toDataURL();
fetch(dataURI)
.then(r=>r.blob())
.then(blob=>{
  // here blob is a good old png file
  var f = new FileReader();
  f.onload = function(){console.log(f.result)};
  f.readAsText(blob);
});
```

```html
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
```

You can achieve the same with XMLHttpRequest.responseType = 'blob' for older browsers.

But if you don't like asynchronicity, you may also convert it manually, by first removing the dataURI header, and then decode the base64 data and feed an Uint8Array with the correct byte values.

```js
var dataURI = c.toDataURL();

var byteString = atob(dataURI.split(',')[1]);
var arr = new Uint8Array(byteString.length);
for (var i = 0; i < byteString.length; i++) {
  arr[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i);
}
var blob = new Blob([arr]);

var f = new FileReader();
f.onload = function(){console.log(f.result)};
f.readAsText(blob);
```

```html
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
```

And note that I didn't talked about [`HTMLCanvasElement.toBlob()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toBlob) yet, because if I'm not mistaken, fabricjs still doesn't have this method, but if you weren't using the `multiplier` option, that would be the best solution.